# Dynamic Knockout table from JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I was trying to populate a table with knockout integration. That takes data from Json.

JSON DATA

```
{
   "info":[
      {
         "Name":"Noob Here",
         "Major":"Language",
         "Sex":"Male",
         "English":"15",
         "Japanese":"5",
         "Calculus":"0",
         "Geometry":"20"
      },
      {
         "Name":"Noob Here",
         "Major":"Calculus",
         "Sex":"Female",
         "English":"0.5",
         "Japanese":"40",
         "Calculus":"20",
         "Geometry":"05"
      }
   ]
}
```

I used knockout-mapping to dynamically map the data into the page. That has been added as Javascript in JS-bin. My script is in the sample's html page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#div1").append("<tr><td data-bind='text: name'></td><td data-bind='text: major'></td><td data-bind='text: sex'></td><td><input data-bind='value: English' /></td><td><input data-bind='value: Japanese' /></td><td><input data-bind='value: Calculus' /></td><td><input data-bind='value: Geometry' /></td></tr>");

    function loadData(fileName) {
        var data = {
            "info": [{
                "Name": "Noob Here",
                    "Major": "Language",
                    "Sex": "Male",
                    "English": "15",
                    "Japanese": "5",
                    "Calculus": "0",
                    "Geometry": "20"
            }, {
                "Name": "Noob Here",
                    "Major": "Calculus",
                    "Sex": "Female",
                    "English": "0.5",
                    "Japanese": "40",
                    "Calculus": "20",
                    "Geometry": "05"
            }]
        }

        return (data);
    }

    var dataFunction = function () {
        this.Items = ko.observableArray([]);
    };

    var myFile = "Data";
    var data = [];

    var data1 = {
        "info": [{
            "Name": "Noob Here",
                "Major": "Language",
                "Sex": "Male",
                "English": "15",
                "Japanese": "5",
                "Calculus": "0",
                "Geometry": "20"
        }, {
            "Name": "Noob Here",
                "Major": "Calculus",
                "Sex": "Female",
                "English": "0.5",
                "Japanese": "40",
                "Calculus": "20",
                "Geometry": "05"
        }]
    }
    if (data1 && data1.info) {
        console.log(data1.info[0]);
        $.each(data1.info[0], function (key, value) {

        });

        $.each(data1.info, function (index, element) {
            data.push({
                English: element.English,
                Japanese: element.Japanese,
                Calculus: element.Calculus,
                Geometry: element.Geometry,
                name: element.Name,
                major: element.Major,
                sex: element.Sex
            });
        });
        dataFunction.prototype = function () {
            var getAllItems = function () {
                var self = this;
                ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self.Items);
            };
            var finalObj = {};
            var info = [];
            $.each(data1.info, function (i, v) {
                var object = {};
                $.each(v, function (i1, val1) {
                    if ($.isNumeric(val1)) {

                        object[i1] = val1
                    }
                });
                info.push(object);
            });
            finalObj['info'] = info;
            console.log(finalObj);
            return {
                getAllItems: getAllItems
            }
        }();
        var dataList = new dataFunction();
        dataList.getAllItems();

        ko.applyBindings(dataList);
    }
});
```

I want to replace

```
data.push({
                English: element.English,
                Japanese: element.Japanese,
                Calculus: element.Calculus,
                Geometry: element.Geometry,
                name: element.Name,
                major: element.Major,
                sex: element.Sex
            });
```

**Into a dynamic script** so that what ever json data i add will be shown in the table format. Even if its column name or column number changes.

Does anyone know how to do it?

http://jsbin.com/ipeseq/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the change in case for name, major and sex is not an actual requirement, you can just push the object.

```
data.push(element);
```

As is you're basically creating a copy of the element piece by piece and pushing that, why not just push the element itself?

Comment: It's not working. As far i understand the data must be pushed as id:value

Comment: you're pushing an object, that you're defining right then as a set of key value pairs.  But you already have an object with key value pairs.  When you say its not working, what do you mean by that?

Comment: Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: major is not defined;
Bindings value: text: major
http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-2.2.1.js
Line 56

Comment: @SreekeshOkky I looked at your sample, but I didn't understand what your goal was.  When you say its not working **what are you trying to do?**

Comment: @SreekeshOkky yep, thats because its defined on element as Major, not major.  That was why I included the disclaimer in the first line of my answer.  If you want arbitrary property names to work, you'll need to try and look up the same ones that you're passing, or find a consistent rule to convert them (like all lower case)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26729/discussion-between-sreekesh-okky-and-ben336)